# Creating a load tester for an upload API with UploadFileAsync

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, console-application

What I am trying to accomplish here is to see how much this API can handle as far as requests per second. I am trying to consume the API in a console app that will ultimately be throwaway code. My idea was to make a for loop that would try to upload an xml document every 2 seconds. I've never done this sort of thing before so forgive my ignorance. Here's my Main method:

```
    static void Main()
    {            
       RunAsync().Wait();         
    }
```

And the RunAsync method:

```
    static async Task RunAsync()
    {

        Uri apiUrl = new Uri("http://apiurl.com/upload/files/uploadfiles");
        const string file = @"C:\simple.xml";

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            client.UploadFileCompleted += FileUploadSuccess;
            client.UploadFileAsync(apiUrl, file);
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Upload waiting 2 seconds...");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Loop completed.");

    }
```

And the success method:

```
    private static void FileUploadSuccess(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string reply = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
        Console.WriteLine("The file result was: {0}", reply);

    }
```

It throws an exception on the first time through on e.Result. Here's the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.dll

After doing some research, apparently I can't call the API method (which returns an async Task) without await'ing it. Unfortunately it seems UploadFileAsync is not "awaitable."

Here's the API method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFiles()
    {
        var pilotTokenObject = TokenHelper.CreatePilotTokenObject(Request);
        byte[] fileBuffer = null;

        HttpResponseMessage retVal = null;
        if (pilotTokenObject != null)
        {
            var content = Request.Content;

            if (content == null)
            {
                throw new PilotApiException("Empty request content", HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
            }
            if (!content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new PilotApiException("Request does not contain not multi-part content");
            }
            var uploadModelController = new PilotUploadModelController();


            //*SAVE STREAMED FILE*
            string serverSavePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PilotUploadApiTempStoragePath"];
            if (!Directory.Exists(serverSavePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(serverSavePath);

            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(serverSavePath);

            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            var fileData = provider.FileData;
            if (fileData == null || fileData.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new PilotApiException("No multipart/form file data present.");
            }

            bool uploaded = false;
            //Loop through each file
            fileData.ForEach((fileRequest) =>
            {
                if (RetryUntilFileReadable(Path.Combine(serverSavePath, fileRequest.LocalFileName), 1000, 5))
                {

                    var fileHeader = fileRequest.Headers;
                    if (fileHeader != null && fileHeader.ContentDisposition != null)
                    {
                        var fileName = fileHeader.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
                        var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(serverSavePath, fileRequest.LocalFileName));


                        //Save File to DB
                        var upload = uploadModelController.UploadHelper
                            .AddUploadFileToDb(pilotTokenObject.CentralUserDbUserId, pilotTokenObject.ClientIp, pilotTokenObject.UserAgentString,
                                UploadEnums.UploadKind.PilotUploadApi, fileName, fileBytes.Length, fileBytes,
                                UploadEnums.EncryptionType.None);

                        if (upload != null)
                            uploaded = true;
                    }
                }

            });



            if (uploaded)
            {
                retVal = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new
                    {
                        Response = String.Format("file uploaded successfully.")
                    });
            }


        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Am I going about this the completely wrong way? Is what I want to do even doable?

Comment: what does  your Web Api method look like?

Comment: Added the API method

Comment: Ok, to clarify, your API doesn't return a task to your client.  It returns a string that is part of an HttpResponseMessage.  So your client has no clue that its a HttpResponseMessage wrapped in a task.  The `await`-ing is strictly within your API method.  Have you tried wrapping your API logic in a try/catch and seeing if you get an exception on the first call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the following would work better in your scenario:

```
byte[] response = await Task.Run(() => client.UploadFile(apiUrl, file));
string reply = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
Console.WriteLine("The file result was: {0}", reply);
Console.WriteLine("Upload waiting 2 seconds...");
await Task.Delay(2000);
```

Trying to mix-and-match the older asynchronous API with the newer async/await doesn't seem fruitful in this case. Better to just wrap the synchronous version of the API with async/await-compatible code.

(Note that it seems to me you could just as well call `Thread.Sleep(2000)` instead of creating a new delay task to wait on, but the above should work fine too).

Comment: Is "response" supposed to be "result"? Otherwise response is unused and result isn't declared.